# end kernel panic not syncing vfs unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0 0) (Recovery mode NO)

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, mount, updates

You will see that I tried to update ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04 which was a 16.04 before (it's an old government laptop, I don't have another pc at hand) and when I rebooted I got that error, I have searched in many forums and they all say to access the recovery mode or to start in live mode, but first, my USB Flash Drive is broken, I don't have another one at home or at hand, I don't even have another pc at hand, and second I have tried many ways but I can't access the advanced options of ubuntu,  It seems that they don't exist or aren't in my GRUB, and I wanted to ask for help or advice, since I can't even flash it, if they had at least one way to get it started, Since considering all the above I have it kind of complicated, if I could get to a terminal, I could try something, but I only have the SHELL and the GRUB is with text, if anyone knows something please tell me

Comment: I can connect my mobile phone to my pc, but I can't buy another usb as the economic situation is complicated, there is no money or credit card etc,

Comment: It seems to be initrd problem, I changed the initrd and booted, but I trusted and restarted the laptop and deleted that extra version of the initrd and I'm back on the same